# Insert function to insert record in SQL table working properly but Update Function to Update Record is not working properly

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert, sql-update

These are my functions to Update student record and Insert Student record in SQL batabase.

```
public void UpdateStudent(ref student stu, string rollno) //Update the values to corresponding roll number 'rollno'
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();  //I have already defined the connection and command
                command = new SqlCommand("update student set FirstName='"+stu.Firstname+"',LastName='"+stu.Lastname+"',YearOfAdmission="+stu.Yearofadmission+",Branch='"+stu.Branch+"' where RollNo='"+rollno+"'", connection); //Yearofadmission is int
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.Close();
        }
    }
public void insertstudent(ref student s)
        {            
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand("insert into student values('"+s.Rollno+"','"+ s.Firstname+"','"+s.Lastname+"',"+s.Yearofadmission+",'"+s.Branch+"','"+s.Password+"')", connection);                 
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;           
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

My second function 'insertstudent' to insert value into SQL table is working correctly and inserting the values properly into database table. But the first function 'Update student' is not updating the values in the databse table. Its is not providing any error either.
So where i am wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be using named parameters instead of concatenating a sql string.

Comment: try capturing the sql that was generated in update and run it in Management studio something to see what it does.. looks like your filter rollno is not matching somehow.

Comment: For sure switch that to sql parameters! If you really want to see the issue, I would put a breakpoint in there and debug up to that point. Than inspect your command to see what its doing. But yeah, scrap that code and switch to http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: You are leaving your self wide open to sql injection attacks. If anyone who uses your software knows a little sql they can easily enter their own queries in your textboxes and delete/update/insert/mess with your data at will. You should be using SqlCommand.Parameters collection like Cam Bruce has stated.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that rollno passed to the update function is correct. If the command is not throwing error, most likely it's executing correctly and ending up updating nothing because no record hits the supplied rollno.

Put a break point at beginning of update function and check the supplied value of rollno.

Also, roll no. in your insert statement is a subset of 's' whereas in update, its provided separately, you may need to check if that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way using parameters. You also need to Dispose of your connection and command objects.

```
 using (connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
    {
    using (command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
    command.CommandText = "update student set FirstName= @FirstName  ,LastName= @LastName, YearOfAdmission= @YearOfAdmission, Branch=@Branch WHERE RollNo= @RollNo";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", stu.FirstName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", stu.LastName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearOfAdmission", stu.YearOfAdmission);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", stu.Branch);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RollNo", stu.RollNo);

       connection.Open();

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: from a security perspective, using named parameters prevents SQL injection. from an ease of use perspective, you don't need to do your own string concatination, and it is much more readable code.